# Can someone please tell me why my code for Checking if two strings are anagram doesnt work

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, anagram

This is my code :

```
string_1 = input("Enter a string : ")
string_2 = input("Enter a second string : ")
a = sorted(string_1)
b = sorted(string_2)
print(a)
print(b)
if a in b and len(a) == len(b):
    print("these strings are anagram")
else:
    print("these strings are not anagram")
```

For example :
Input:
Enter a string :  mounir
Enter a second string :  mounir
Output :

['i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 'u']
['i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 'u']
these strings are not anagram

Comment: `a in b` isn't doing what you expect.  It's checking to see if `a` is an *element* of `b`.  But you can replace that entire test (including the length comparison) with `if a == b:`.

Comment: @TomKarzes But if the list a and the list b are equal, then shouldn't a  be an element of b?,

Comment: `a` is a list, not one of the letters in the list `b`.

Comment: @JohnColeman ohh. so it doesnt make sense to python to ask if a list is in another list? the "in" operator only works for elements ?

Comment: @user20194358 In this case it doesn't make sense, although there are applications which involve lists of lists.

Comment: Everything can be an element. However, this kind of element testing considers the left-hand side as a *single* thing, even if that left-hand side happens to be a sequence (such as a list). For example `['i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 'u']` **would** be `in [['i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 'u']]` (notice the extra pair of brackets).

Comment: As an aside, this test is not adequate. For example, the length of `'foo'` and `'off'` is the same, and every letter that can be found in `'foo'` can also be found in `'off'`, but they are not anagrams. Sorting the lists **doesn't help** with your approach; but once the lists have been sorted, it is simple to do a *correct* anagram check: simply check if the results are *equal*. See the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: @user20194358 Consider the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`.  It has three elements:  `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.  Period.  The list itself, `['a', 'b', 'c']` is not one of those three, so it is not al element of itself.  If you do `a in b`, all this is asking is whether `a` is an element of `b`.  Just what you'd expect from the word `in`.  This is simple, simple stuff.  You should understand it in seconds.  Do some tests.  Start up Python, create a list, then test the `in` operator.

Answer (score -1):

you should try with this one. I changed the condition.

```
string_1 = input("Enter a string : ")
string_2 = input("Enter a second string : ")
a = sorted(string_1)
b = sorted(string_2)
print(a)
print(b)
if sorted(a) == sorted(b):
print("these strings are anagram")
else:
    print("these strings are not anagram")
```